# "String or binary data would be truncated" error when value is same size as column size

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a customer table in SQL Server 2012 with 'status' column is of type varchar(1).

This statement is giving a 'String or binary data would be truncated' error

```
exec sp_executesql N'update customer set status=''@stat'' 
where custID=@custID',N'@stat varchar(1),@custID bigint',@stat='B',@custID=940
```

I don't know why because I am passing 'B' as a single character. I get the same error if `@stat=''`

However this statement runs fine:

```
 exec sp_executesql N'update customer set status=''B'' 
where custid=@custID',N'@custID bigint',@custID=940
```

It seems there's a subtle issue I am missing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mistakenly trying to set `status` to the literal string `'@stat'`, not the value of the variable `@stat`. The string `'@stat'` has five characters, and would be truncated when inserting into a `VARCHAR(1)`. Try:

```
exec sp_executesql N'update customer set status=@stat 
where custID=@custID',N'@stat varchar(1),@custID bigint',@stat='B',@custID=940
```